# 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_excel'

Tags: python, pandas

When converting .xlsx file to html using panda library

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame.read_excel('trial_xls.xlsx')
table = df.to_html()

df = pandas.DataFrame.read_excel('trial_xls.xlsx')
```

I'm facing the following error

```
AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'read_excel'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss with your code. You have to write `df = pandas.read_excel('trial_xls.xlsx')`

`read_excel` is a function of `pandas` not a method of `Dataframe`.

Look here for more info:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: HI,,                                                                                                             
How to see whether xlsx file is converted to html or not ,,i tried like this display (table) eventhough its not working,,